# JAVA google spreadsheet batchUpdate API : com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 409 Conflict

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In my java spring boot application, I am using google spreadsheet API's but sometimes (very rarely) I got the below exception from `batchUpdate` API.

Below is the code :-

```
 BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        requestBody.setRequests(requests);
        Sheets sheetService = googleConfigConstant.getSheetService();
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate reques = 
 sheetService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, requestBody);
```

Exception what I am getting :-

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 409 
Conflict
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/dummy-spreadsheet-id:batchUpdate? 
quotaUser=testuser
{
 "code" : 409,
 "errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "global",
  "message" : "The operation was aborted.",
  "reason" : "aborted"
 } ],
 "message" : "The operation was aborted.",
 "status" : "ABORTED"
}
```

After searching a lot I am not able to find the root cause, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any scenario where this behavior reproduces consistently? This can definitely be caused by hitting some API quota (per caller, per project and/or too many requests in a short period of time). Do you have an [exponential back-off](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff) logic implemented on your script? That might sort intermittent issues of this nature. On another note, It’ll help to understand which operations were in the batchUpdate request to troubleshoot it. If you can provide it, please make sure to redact sensitive information.